# best strategy to moderate uploaded images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to finalize my image moderation code,
I have just a simple assets model with a column moderated.
Images will not be shown unless the moderated flag is set to true ( boolean )

In addition to this I have the idea to store a `is_moderated (integer)` inside User model and store a value there like

- 0 = not moderated
- 1 = moderated and inappropriate image
- 2 = moderated and correct image

Then in application controller I do something like, in before filter:

```
def is_moderated

  if user_signed_in?

    @moderate = Moderate.find(current_user) rescue nil

      if @user.is_moderated == "2"
        render :template => "shared/moderated_bad_images"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you are only allowed to upload 1 image initially.

Then after that image is deemed appropriate you can add more.

Comment: thats an idea also yes, a smart one indeed since the first picture is the profile picture